# Best approach to implement this design [ios]

Tags: ios, uitableview, grid, uicollectionview

What would be the best approach to implementing a design like the one below?

Couple of things:

- Level cell can fall between any 4 cells on the grid
- Whole board is scrollable

I'm leaning toward UICollectionView but I'm not exactly sure how to do the "level cell." One of the approach might be to split the level image into four and draw them on each cell? I'm not sure if that's the best solution, however.

More info:

- The gray boxes are just game actions. Based on the actions, the app determine if they reached the next level. In the design, it only shows level 6 but it will really have level 1,2,3.. all the way up to 200.

[image: level grid design]

Comment: This is a great question. According to me using a diamond view on top the `UICollectionView` is definitely a bad solution and not maintainable as you will have trouble while scrolling and screen rotating. I would use 0 margin for item separations and have 5 different item types. This seems like a more stable solution. I am not sure if the diamond view is intuitive. Which items are LVL6 in the diagram? It doesn't make a sharp dissection of the items. Is the first LVL6 item the first row and fourth one? If thats the case what happens when first LVL6 item is in the first column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to use a collection view with 2 different kinds of cells; one for the rounded rect shape, and one for the cell with a cut corner. In this approach, the "level cell", as you called it, wouldn't be a cell at all, but a separate view added to the collection view. This would allow you to use the default UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

I added 2 different cells to the collection view in the storyboard, and gave them the appropriate class and unique identifiers. The code in `RDCutCornerCell` creates the rounded rect with the bottom right corner cut off, and has a method to rotate that shape as needed. Here's the code for that class,

```
#import "RDCutCornerCell.h"
#define CUT 10
#define LINEWIDTH 2

@interface RDCutCornerCell ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *outline;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentPosition;
@end



@implementation RDCutCornerCell


-(void)rotateToPosition:(NSInteger) position {
    if (! self.shapeLayer) {
        self.shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, LINEWIDTH/2.0, LINEWIDTH/2.0);
        self.outline = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [self.outline moveToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + CUT, bounds.origin.y)];
        [self.outline addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width - CUT, bounds.origin.y)];
        [self.outline addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width - CUT, bounds.origin.y + CUT) radius:CUT startAngle:-M_PI/2.0 endAngle:0 clockwise:YES];
        [self.outline addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2.0)];
        [self.outline addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2.0, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height)];
        [self.outline addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + CUT, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height)];
        [self.outline addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + CUT, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height - CUT) radius:CUT startAngle:M_PI/2.0 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
        [self.outline addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y + CUT)];
        [self.outline addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + CUT, bounds.origin.y + CUT) radius:CUT startAngle:M_PI endAngle:3*M_PI/2.0 clockwise:YES];
        [self.shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:240/255.0 blue:175/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
        [self.shapeLayer setLineWidth:LINEWIDTH];
        [self.shapeLayer setPath:self.outline.CGPath];
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];
    }

    CGFloat angle = (M_PI/2) * (position - self.currentPosition);
    CGRect boundingRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(self.outline.CGPath);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(boundingRect), CGRectGetMidY(boundingRect));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.outline applyTransform:transform];
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
    [self.outline applyTransform:transform];
    [self.shapeLayer setPath:self.outline.CGPath];
    self.currentPosition = position;
}
```

I created a simple UIView subclass to create the "level cell",

```
@implementation DiamondView

-(void)addLayer {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.label = [UILabel new];
    self.label.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.label.frame = self.bounds;
    self.label.text = @"LVL\n6";
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self addSubview:self.label];
    CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.bounds.size.width*0.12 , self.bounds.size.width*0.12) cornerRadius:8];
    CGRect boundingRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path.CGPath);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(boundingRect), CGRectGetMidY(boundingRect));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI/4.0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
    [path applyTransform:transform];
    shape.path = path.CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

The collection view controller was set up to have 5 columns of cells like in your question, but that can be changed with the #defines at the top of the file. I have a single property, startIndexForCutCells, that determines where the left upper cell of the four cells with cut corners shows up in the collection view.

```
#define CELLS_ACROSS 5 // number of cells per row
#define CELL_GAP 10 // interitem spacing for the cells

@interface RDCollectionViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger startIndexForCutCells;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat cellWidth;
@property (strong,nonatomic) DiamondView *diamond;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *cutCellIndexes;
@end

@implementation RDCollectionViewController {
    CGFloat gap;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = CELL_GAP;
    self.cellWidth = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - (CELLS_ACROSS - 1) * CELL_GAP)/CELLS_ACROSS;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth);
    _startIndexForCutCells = -100;
}


-(void)setStartIndexForCutCells:(NSInteger)startIndexForCutCells {
    _startIndexForCutCells = startIndexForCutCells;
    self.cutCellIndexes = @[@(_startIndexForCutCells), @(_startIndexForCutCells + 1), @(_startIndexForCutCells + CELLS_ACROSS + 1), @(_startIndexForCutCells + CELLS_ACROSS)];
    if (! self.diamond) {
        self.diamond = [[DiamondView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth)];
        [self.collectionView addSubview:self.diamond];
        [self.diamond addLayer];
    }
    self.diamond.center = [self setCenterForIndex:self.startIndexForCutCells];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}




-(CGPoint)setCenterForIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    NSInteger column = index % CELLS_ACROSS + 1;
    NSInteger row = (index/CELLS_ACROSS) + 1;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(column*(self.cellWidth + CELL_GAP) - CELL_GAP/2 , row*(self.cellWidth + CELL_GAP) - CELL_GAP/2);
    return center;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 90;
}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self.cutCellIndexes containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]) {
        RDCutCornerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CutCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger position = [self.cutCellIndexes indexOfObject:@(indexPath.row)];
        [cell rotateToPosition:position];
        return cell;

    }else{
        RDRoundedSquareCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ((indexPath.row + 1) % CELLS_ACROSS != 0) { // don't allow pick on the last column
        self.startIndexForCutCells = indexPath.row;
    }

}
```

This code produced this result after clicking on the third cell in the third row,

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach. Are you adding the DimondView on top of the whole collectionview? If you need to do that, do you need 5 different cells? Can't you just have one type and just add the DimondView where it's needed?

Comment: @SJonRails, I only have 2 kinds of cells (I originally had 5, but I updated my code to use only 2). Yes, the diamondView is added to the collection view as a subview.

Comment: @SJonRails I see you've added a bounty. Why does my approach not answer your question?

Comment: I was hoping for an approach that require you to add a view over a subview. Doesn't seem too auto-layout friendly. However, at this point, the bounty is all yours :)

Comment: @SJonRails I don't understand that comment. What do you mean by "approach that require you to add a view over a subview"? Did you mean *doesn't* require adding a view over a subview?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. A typo :)

Comment: @SJonRails the cells of a collection view aren't laid out using auto layout anyway (subviews inside the cells can be), so I certainly don't see any problem with adding a subview this way.

Comment: So what happens if you rotate the device? The cells will obviously move but the dimondview will be at the fixed frame it was added on.

Comment: @SJonRails It's not only then diamond view, but also the two cut-corner cells on the bottom that you would need to adjust, so it would take more work to make this compatible with rotation.  You would have to figure out how many rows across you have when in landscape, so you would know which columns to put the modified cells, and the diamond view in.